# You did not select a file to upload. PHP Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, controller

I am trying to implement a post functionality and want to pick message and image from a php view. My message functionality is working good. But on image upload i receive an error `You did not select a file to upload`. This is my controller function

```
function post_func()
{
    session_start();
    echo $post_message=$_POST['post'];
    echo $share_with=$_POST['share_with'];
    echo $image=$_POST['image'];
    if($image==null){
        echo "<br/>no image<br/>";  
    }
    else{
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $config['upload_path'] = './application/css';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';


            $this->load->library('upload', $config);


            $this->upload->initialize($config);



            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                echo "<br/>";
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                echo "<br/> image error<br/>";
            }
            else
            {

                echo "<br/> reached <br/>";
                session_start();
                $this->membership_model->insert_images($this->upload->data(),$email);
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                echo "<br/ problem<br/>";
            }




        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
    $public;
    if($share_with=="public"){
        echo "1";
        $public=true;
    }else{
        echo "0";
        $public=false;
    }echo "-----------------------------<br/>";
    echo $user=$this->session->userdata('user_identification');
    $data = array 
            (
                'userid'=> $user,
                'public' => $public,
                'message' => $post_message,
                'picname' => "None"
            );
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $this->membership_model->add_message($data);
    echo "</br>";
    echo $user=$this->session->userdata('user_identification');
}
```

This is my view.

```
<?php echo form_open('search/post_func');?>

<!--<form id="loginForm" action="../search/post_func" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >-->
<div id="your_post">
<div id="post_image">
<img   id ="post_img" src="<?php  echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?><?php echo '/application/css/'. $img ?>"/>
</div>
<textarea name="post" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Share an update..." id="post_text" rows="2" value=""></textarea>

//other view items
            <?php
    echo form_close();
    ?>
```

Please help me

Comment: Take a look here first:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: Your Form must be multipart.

Comment: @Ts8060 i have added `<?php echo form_open_multipart('search/post_func');?>` but it still gives the error.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('search/post_func');?>
```

Comment: I have define set the name of my input `image` in this code '<input name="image" type="file" id="attach" />' even then it says `image not defined` @Nil'z

Comment: i have added `<?php echo form_open_multipart('search/post_func');?>` but it still gives the error.

Comment: `$this->upload->do_upload()` expects a `field_name`, You have not provided that, that means by default it will take `user_file`. Do you have a `<input type="file" name="user_file">` in your form? The other thing is that you don't take file's like this `echo $image=$_POST['image'];`, Instead do this : `echo $image=$_FILES['image'];`. Hope it helps.

Comment: my code exactly like @SSMA code and i updated your answer also but still i am getting `You did not select a file to upload.` error in my page, can u help me? i restarted wamp server also but same issue.

Comment: My multipart code is `<?php echo form_open_multipart("search/data", array("onsubmit"=>"return validateSearch()")); ?>`

Comment: i am getting file basename using `$_FILES['file']['name']` in controller but file not uploading, getting error `You did not select a file to upload.`

Comment: if using pure html. enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: god bless u my dear

Comment: Every single time I forget this. I've visited this question more than 3 times now...

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I realized this was the problem after some research

Comment: In addition to that, as @mzalazar said, you need to provide the **`name` attribute** to the method `$this->upload->do_upload('my_file_input_name')`, too.

Answer (score 32):

Change:

```
$this->upload->do_upload()
```

To this:

```
$this->upload->do_upload('my_file_input_name')
```

and it will work!! :)

Comment: i changed like this but getting `You did not select a file to upload.` , i uploaded my question in accepted answer, will you see that?

Comment: @151291 check in firefox/chrome console (in "network" tab) if your form is being sent.

Comment: yes it is sending POST like that and repeating. `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$config['upload_path'].$basename);` working but `$this->upload->do_upload('test')` not working.

Comment: You have to replace 'test' with the name of the file element in the HTML, letme know.

Comment: sure it did! but wonder why ? i have worked with the empty parameters before

Answer (score 3):

Your form type should be "multipart"
 Change your form tag to:

```
 <?php echo form_open_multipart('search/post_func');?>
```

Comment: I added my question in accepted answer can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

you should put previous attribute in form tag

```
$this->upload->do_upload('file_name')
```

pass input tag file name to pervious line in your controller

```
<input type="file"   name ="file_name" >
```

Answer (score 1):

example code is

```
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload');
            $this->upload->initialize($config);  

    if ( ! $this->upload-> do_upload('userfile'))
    {

                   $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                   $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $errors);
                       redirect('ur_link');
    }
    else
    { 
                            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                            $fullpath= $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
                            $file_name = $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
                    }
    }
```

Comment: $this->upload-> do_upload('userfile') // userfile is the name of your file

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['profile_pic']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['profile_pic']['name'])){

    $config['upload_path']= './assets/img/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = 10000;
    $config['max_width'] = 10000;
    $config['max_height'] = 10000;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('profile_pic'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        print_r($error);
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        if(!empty($data)){

            $img1 =  $data['upload_data']['file_name'];                           

        }
    }
}

$insert_data['profile_pic'] = $img1;
```

Comment: this looking mostly code can you please add  some information

Answer (score 0):

Another reason I find this problem to be occurred. if you forget to initialize after load your library:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$this->upload->initialize($config); //Make this line must be here.
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: I tried all answer from here but still getting error like`You did not select a file to upload.` but `$_FILES['file']['name']` works fine.

Comment: Why dont you post your own question so we can find out the solution for your problem.

Comment: my question is same but error is different... ok if i did not get i will post my question.. `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$config['upload_path'].$basename);` working but `do_upload` not working.

Answer (score 0):

So note I was doing a mysql upload import and I got the "You did not select a file to upload" message. It turns out my import sql file had extra columns which caused the fail and returned this error message.